# Generator of a product $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let

- $I\subseteq\mathbb R$;
- $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space;
- $\pi_J$ denote the projection from $E^I$ onto $E^J$ for $J\subseteq I$ and $\pi_i:=\pi_\{i\}$ for $i\in I$.

By definition, the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal E^{\otimes I}$ on $E^I$ is given by $$\mathcal E^{\otimes I}:=\sigma(\pi_i,i\in I)$$ and the $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal E^{\otimes J}$ on $E^J$, for any $J\subseteq I$, are defined accordingly.

> **Question 1**: If $J\subseteq I$, are we able to show that $\sigma(\pi_J)=\sigma(\pi_j,j\in J)$?

This is claim seems to be so trivial that I'm not able to prove it. By definition, $\sigma(\pi_J)=\pi_J^{-1}(\mathcal E^{\otimes J})$ and it's clear to me that $\pi_J$ is $(\mathcal E^{\otimes I},\mathcal E^{\otimes J})$-measurable.

---

Now let $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space and $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ be an $(E,\mathcal E)$-valued process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$. If $J\subseteq I$, we may consider the random variable $$X_J:=(X_j)_{j\in J}:\Omega\to E^J.$$

> **Question 2**: Let $\mathcal F^Y$ denote the filtration generated by any process $Y$. Are we able to show that $\mathcal F^X_t=X_I^{-1}(\mathcal F^\pi_t)$ for all $t\in I$?

Let $t\in I$ and $J:=\{s\in I:s\le t\}$. By definition, $$\mathcal F^\pi_t=\sigma(\pi_s,s\in J)=\mathcal E^{\otimes J}\tag1.$$ On the other hand, $$\mathcal F^X_t=\sigma(X_s,s\in J)\tag2$$ and if the claim in Question 1 is correct, then $$\sigma(X_J)=X_J^{-1}(\mathcal E^{\otimes J})=X_I^{-1}(\pi_J^{-1}(\mathcal E^{\otimes J}))=X_I^{-1}(\mathcal F^\pi_t)\tag3.$$ So, if that's correct, all that remains to show would be $$\sigma(X_s,s\in J)=\sigma(X_J)\tag4,$$ which seems again to be the same question as in Question 1.

Comment: As you defined $\mathcal E^{\otimes J}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $E^J$. On the other hand,  $\pi_J$ denote the projection from $E^I$ onto $E^J$, so $\sigma(\pi_J)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $E^I$ (not $E^J$). In question 1, shouldn't it be: show that $\mathcal E^{\otimes I}:=\sigma(\pi_J)$?

Comment: @Ramiro Sorry, my definition of $\mathcal E^{\otimes J}$ was broken. Please see my edit. In general, if $J$ is any index set, then $\mathcal E^{\otimes J}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the projections of $E^J$ onto the coordinates.

Comment: $\mathcal E^{\otimes J}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $E^J$ and $\sigma(\pi_J)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $E^I$. So $\mathcal E^{\otimes J} \neq \sigma(\pi_J)$. Maybe, in question 1, you meant $\mathcal E^{\otimes I} = \sigma(\pi_J)$.

Comment: @Ramiro There was a second error in question 1, you're right. Fixed now!

Comment: Since $\mathcal E^{\otimes J}:=\sigma(\pi_i,i\in J)$, you didn't really change questions 1.

Comment: @Ramiro Now you're making the same mistake as I did before. For clarity: Let $\pi^{J'}_J:E^{J'}\to E^J$ denote the projection for $J\subseteq J'\subseteq I$. Then $\mathcal E^{\otimes J}=\sigma(\pi^J_j,j\in J)$ for all $J\subseteq I$. So, $\sigma(\pi^J_j,j\in J)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $E^J$, while $\sigma(\pi_j,j\in J)=\sigma(\pi^I_j,j\in J)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $E^I$.

Comment: Perhaps, you should add to the question the remark that all $\pi_i$  and $\pi_J$ have a fixed domain $E^I$.

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please, upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right when you say that the results you need for **Question 1** and **Question 2** are rather obvious (or trivial). However, we need some care when proving them. Here are detailed proofs.

Let us start with a lemma:

**Lemma**: Let $(Y, \Sigma)$ be a measure space and let $S \subseteq \Sigma$ be such that $\Sigma =\sigma(S)$.  Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a function. Then,
$$\sigma(f)= \sigma (\{f^{-1}(D) : D\in S\})$$

**Proof**: Since  $S \subseteq \Sigma$, we clearly have
$$\sigma (\{f^{-1}(D) : D\in S\}) \subseteq \sigma (\{f^{-1}(C) : C\in \Sigma\})= \sigma(f) \tag{1}$$

Now, let
$ \Gamma =\{B \subseteq Y : f^{-1}(B) \in \sigma (\{f^{-1}(D) : D\in S\})$.

Note that

1. $\emptyset \in \Gamma$
2. if $B \in \Gamma$ then $f^{-1}(B) \in \sigma (\{f^{-1}(D) : D\in S\})$. So,
   $$f^{-1}(B^c) = (f^{-1}(B))^c \in \sigma (\{f^{-1}(D) : D\in S\}) $$
   so $B^c \in \Gamma$.
3. If, for all $i \in \Bbb N$,  $B_i \in \Gamma$, we have $f^{-1}(B_i) \in \sigma (\{f^{-1}(D) : D\in S\})$. So
   $$f^{-1} \left(\bigcup_i B_i \right)= \bigcup_i f^{-1}(B_i) \in \sigma (\{f^{-1}(D) : D\in S\}) $$

so $\bigcup_i B_i \in \Gamma$.

So $\Gamma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Clearly $S \subseteq \Gamma$. So, $\Sigma = \sigma(S) \subseteq \Gamma$. But that means that, for all $C \in \Sigma$, $f^{-1}(C)  \in \sigma (\{f^{-1}(D) : D\in S\})$. So,
$$\{f^{-1}(C) : C\in \Sigma\} \subseteq \sigma (\{f^{-1}(D) : D\in S\})$$
So
$$ \sigma(f) = \sigma (\{f^{-1}(C) : C\in \Sigma\}) \subseteq \sigma (\{f^{-1}(D) : D\in S\}) \tag{2}$$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have $\sigma(f)= \sigma (\{f^{-1}(D) : D\in S\})$. This completes the proof of the lemma. $\square$

Now,

1. Let $I\subseteq \Bbb R$ and $J\subseteq I$ be two fixed sets;
2. Let $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space;
3. For all $i \in I$, let $\pi_i: E^I \rightarrow E$ be the projection from $E^I$ onto $E$ corresponding to $i$.
4. We define $\mathcal E^{\otimes I}= \sigma(\pi_i: i \in I) = \sigma(\{\pi_i^{-1}(A): A \in \mathcal E \text{ and } i \in I\})$
5. For all $j \in J$, let $\rho_j: E^J \rightarrow E$ be the projection from $E^J$ onto $E$ corresponding to $j$.
6. We define $\mathcal E^{\otimes J}= \sigma(\rho_j: i \in J) = \sigma(\{\rho_j^{-1}(A): A \in \mathcal E \text{ and } j \in J\})$

Let  $\pi_J : E^I \rightarrow E^J$ be the projection from  $E^I$ onto $E^J$. Note that, for all $j \in J$, we have $\pi_j= \rho_j \circ \pi_J$

Let us prove

> **Question 1**: $\sigma(\pi_J)=\sigma(\pi_j,j\in J)$

**Proof**:
We have
\begin{align*}
\sigma(\pi_J) & = \sigma(\{\pi_J^{-1}(B): B \in \mathcal E^{\otimes J} ) &\\
&= \sigma(\{\pi_J^{-1}(\rho_j^{-1}(A)): A \in \mathcal E \text{ and } j \in J ) & \text{ by the lemma} \\
&= \sigma(\{(\rho_j \circ \pi_J)^{-1}(A): A \in \mathcal E \text{ and } j \in J ) & \\
&= \sigma(\{\pi_j^{-1}(A): A \in \mathcal E \text{ and } j \in J ) & \\
&= \sigma(\pi_j: j \in J)
\end{align*}
This completes the proof. $\square$

**Remark**: Regarding **Question 2**, your argument is correct. For the last step you need

> Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space and $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ be an $(E,\mathcal E)$-valued process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$. If $J\subseteq I$, we may consider the random variable $$X_J:=(X_j)_{j\in J}:\Omega\to E^J.$$
> Then $\sigma(X_J)= \sigma(X_j,j\in J)$

**Proof** It is similar to proof of **Question 1**.

Note that, for all $j \in J$, we have $X_j= \rho_j \circ X_J$.

We have
\begin{align*}
\sigma(X_J) & = \sigma(\{X_J^{-1}(B): B \in \mathcal E^{\otimes J} ) &\\
&= \sigma(\{X_J^{-1}(\rho_j^{-1}(A)): A \in \mathcal E \text{ and } j \in J ) & \text{ by the lemma} \\
&= \sigma(\{(\rho_j \circ X_J)^{-1}(A): A \in \mathcal E \text{ and } j \in J ) & \\
&= \sigma(\{X_j^{-1}(A): A \in \mathcal E \text{ and } j \in J ) & \\
&= \sigma(X_j: j \in J)
\end{align*}